# plocate taking very long with database init

Tags: software-installation

This is my first time asking anything here, so I have no clue how askubuntu works, I guess

I tried installing plocate, with hopes it would not take long. Multiple posts said it would take seconds, a couple minutes max. My ubuntu server install (22.04.1 LTS) has been installing plocate and stuck on initialization for 5 hours now. Is there any way to either cancel the installation, or skip the initialization? ctrl+c stops it, but apt just tells me to do sudo dpkg --configure -a, which brings me back to where i am now. Any help? I can't find this issue anywhere else.

Comment: Do you have some particularly large volume (such as a mounted backup drive) that it is indexing unnecessarily? If so, you could look at excluding it via the /etc/updatedb.conf file

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it was taking so long I had to quit with `ctrl-C` but I later found it was blocking other processes and downloads after running this command `ps aux | grep -i apt`.

After going through this [article](https://cloudlinuxtech.com/could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend/), I killed the process with `sudo fuser -vki -TERM /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` in the terminal, and entered `sudo dpkg --configure --pending`, but the problem persisted until I ran the following commands

- `type updatedb updatedb`
- `rpm -qf /usr/bin/updatedb`
- `sudo apt-get remove plocate -y`.

If that does not work, you can google how to uninstall a package. I guess you can also run `which plocate` to find its path, navigate to it, then delete it by running `sudo rm plocate`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with plocate as soon as I started the install.

My solution was to do following commands:

```
which plocate
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm -rf plocate
find iname plocate
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
rpm -qf /usr/bin/updatedb
sudo apt remove plocate -y
```

Hope this helps. And also thankyou to olalekan for the initial help